# Animated SVG sprite in IMG tag vibrates in horizontal direction

Tags: animation, svg, sprite

See code snippet for bouncing circle in 24 sprite frames.

`<text y='12'>n:0</text>` displays the sprite framenr

How can I get rid of the horizontal *jitter* movement, is it SVG or CSS?

The offset is less at less frames in sprite, and gets worse and worse at more frames per sprite

It is less obvious in Chromium, and more obvious in FireFox

I tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/preserveAspectRatio

```html
<style>
  #bounce {
    --w: 200px;
    width: var(--w);
    height: var(--w);
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-flex;
    background: lightgreen;
  }

  img {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    animation: moveX 1s steps(23) infinite;
  }

  @keyframes moveX {
    to {
      transform: translate(-100%);
      left: 100%;
    }
  }

</style>
<div id="bounce"><img id=svgimg src="SVG injected here"></div>
<script>
  window.onload = () => svgimg.src = `data:image/svg+xml,` + svg.innerHTML;
</script>
<template id=svg>
  <svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' viewBox='0 0 2400 100' height='200'>
    <style>
      ellipse {
        fill: none;
        stroke: green;
        stroke-width: 5;
      }

    </style>
    <g transform='translate(0 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='32' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:0</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(100 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='32.3' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:1</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(200 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='33.2' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:2</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(300 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='34.5' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:3</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(400 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='36.5' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:4</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(500 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='39' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:5</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(600 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='42' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:6</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(700 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='45.7' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:7</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(800 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='49.8' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:8</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(900 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='54.5' rx='31.3' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:9</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1000 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='59.8' rx='33.9' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:10</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1100 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='65.7' rx='36.9' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:11</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1200 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='72' rx='40' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:12</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1300 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='65.7' rx='36.9' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:13</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1400 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='59.8' rx='33.9' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:14</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1500 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='54.5' rx='31.3' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:15</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1600 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='49.8' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:16</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1700 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='45.7' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:17</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1800 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='42' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:18</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(1900 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='39' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:19</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(2000 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='36.5' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:20</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(2100 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='34.5' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:21</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(2200 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='33.2' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:22</text>
    </g>
    <g transform='translate(2300 0)'>
      <ellipse cx='50' cy='32.3' rx='30' ry='30'></ellipse><text y='12'>n:23</text>
    </g>
  </svg></template>
```

#### Note

I can **not** use a library, I am generating (and changing) spritesheets **Client-Side**

Template for this circle is a *template-literal*:

```
<template id="bounce">
  <ellipse cx='50' 
           cy='${72-1*ease(40)}' 
           rx='${minmax(30,40-ease(20))}' 
           ry='30' fill='none' stroke='black' stroke-width='5'>
  </ellipse>
  <text y='12'>n:${framenr}</text>
</template>
```

A Web Component then (re)creates the sprite and IMG, and everything to display the sprite

`<svg-spriter do="bounce" steps="24" duration="1s" animation="infinite"></svg-spriter>`

Comment: Why are you doing this so hard? Can you use any javascript animation library that will solve either inprecise ellipse alignments (calculated) or browser handling of stroke-width in SVG (try 5.5 for example)?

Comment: Can't use a library, I am generating (and changing) spritesheets clientside

Comment: Then hopefully one other developer will jump in (really have stopped developing SVG animation manually without javascript unless it's paid huge ...). Try changing the stroke width to 5.5px as I have instructed you above (always use units in SVG to avoid confusion).

Comment: And I would also check BBox widths of all ellipses with a simple javascript loop e.g. document.querySelectorAll("ellipse").forEach and output elem.getBBox().width and maybe even more relevant elem.getBBox().left. The point is to find "outliers" for frame steps that you can then fix.

Comment: I tried, its not the ellipse stroke; its the whole SVG "frame" alignment. tnx for your effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have made some changes to the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/phv156Lb/), and it seems to work. One point seems to be that the last `left` coordinate in the transformation should be the total length of the `svg` minus the length of the window. In the fiddle, you can change

```
transform: translate(calc(-1 * var(--steps) * var(--w)));
```

to

```
transform: translate(calc(-1 * calc(var(--steps) - 1) * var(--w)));
```

In your snippet, the `transform: translate(-100%);` percentage should be `(2300/2400)*100`.

More importantly, I have added the `width='2400'` property to the `svg`. The matter of setting a missing length property for an svg is quite complex, and I do not think that every browser behaves the same way.

In the fiddle, I have changed the `--w` property to 100, which is the height and width of each svg frame. If you want to set it to 200, you would need to change the size of the svg and the coordinates of each frame proportionally.

Comment: Yes! Took some struggling.. Do CSS properties have types? I think my ``--steps`` is a string; so I had to do: ``transform: translate(calc(-1px * var(--steps) * var(--w)));``

Comment: Yes, CSS has units, and they are important. At first I thought it might be an issue, then I realised that `--w` has `px` units, and it should not be necessary. You can see in the fiddle that I left a `+0px` to see whether there might be an error.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my tuesday.. this is what I am doing: https://jsfiddle.net/dannye/eh9zb10q/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears it's something with your frame alignment. If I draw all ellipsis without translation and with opacity of 0.05 it gives this image:

[image: Elipses drawn all at once]

And by first look it is OK though the thickness of bold green is somehow one pixel less on the left. So it might be worth to try with odd width of ellipse in its "air" positions.

BTW SVG (specification) also has *shape-rendering* parameter that you might use yet this should rarely be an issue in your case:

[SVG shape-rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering)